# Installing two different versions of Hugo (ubuntu)

Tags: hugo

I have multiple Hugo websites. And some of their themes is not compatible with the newer versions of Hugo. After struggling enough with the errors, I gave up and wanted to have different versions installed for the respective websites. I learned there is a quick way if you use macOS with brew (`brew switch hugo 0.27` for example) but none for Ubuntu Linux. I might have a complete solution if I install Golang and create different virtual environments for each website but I am looking for a quick workaround solution like the brew example.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution exists for ubuntu as well. Hugo binaries do not need to be installed and can be run directly from the bin folder. So you need to download the versions you need from the [Github releases repository](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases) then you need to change the name of the Hugo file as you wish. (renaming with version number would help to remember it later i.e. hugo0583 for hugo_0.58.3 for example) then move it to the bin folder with `sudo mv hugo0583 /usr/local/bin/hugo0583` command. and finally, use Hugo commands with the new name and you are good to go.